# Run code before every file

Tags: php, apache

I built a website using PHP 5.3 (with Apache 2.4).

I have global file that needs to run before every page (to set timezone and more global settings).
So in each file I must to remember to include it in the top of the page. It is not convenient.

Is there any way to set a boot file that runs automatically before every file?

Comment: If you bootstrapped your code, you wouldn't need to do this hackish method.  You could simply include this functionality in your global bootstrap file.

Comment: How to set bootstrap file?

Comment: That is what I did until now, and that is what I am tring to avoid

Comment: Axel is not referring to that. Here is what he means: http://www.jigsawboys.com/2009/09/17/how-to-bootstrap-php-code/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can use this php config directive:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

auto_prepend_file string

> Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the
>   main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require
>   function, so include_path is used.